# Galois field with MATLAB

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, matlab

I am interested in working with Galois field in MATLAB.
Can any one explain for me with example if it possible the following definition:

I know $GF(2)=\{0,1\}$, but what does $GF(2^m)$ mean? 
If $m=3$, can any one give me the table of addition and multiplication, and if it possible some MATLAB function, please?

Comment: Can you give an example how to construct the table of addition and multiplication, the are modulo 2 or 8 if $m=3$?

Comment: I suggest to search the $GF$ word in the Matlab help!

Comment: ok but I need how to construct the table without Matlab, in the case $GF(2^m)$ and $m=2$.

Comment: The multiplication table for $GF(4)$ you can find on your own from this very simple fact: The non-zero elements of a field always makes a group under multiplication. Which group could that be in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the function gf in Matlab. It convert numbers from range $0$ to $2^m-1$ to an object in $GF(2^m)$

$GF(2^m)$ is a finite field with $2^m$ elements. It can be generated using a primitive root from a primitive polynomial.

This [Mathwork document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/error-detection-and-correction.html#fp6358)  teach us how to create multiplication table and addition table. Read the section on arithmetic on galois field.

Edit:

primitive polynomial: $1+x+x^2$.

The elements are $1, \alpha, 1+\alpha, 0$.

Multiplication of $1$ and $0$ are trivial.

$$\alpha(\alpha) = \alpha^2 = \alpha +1$$

$$\alpha(\alpha+1)=\alpha^2+\alpha=1$$

$$(\alpha+1)(\alpha+1)=\alpha^2+1=\alpha$$

Comment: ok can you give and example for multiplication table of $GF(2^2)$ please

Comment: edited to include how to do that by hand.